# .app file firmware unpacking

Tags: firmware, unpacking

For analyzing firmware , I want to unpack the following firmware:

https://www.inmarsat.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Explorer_100_110_V2-11-3.zip
After unzip, I've got file named "N03_A_E_D_02_11_03.APP". Firstly, I want to unpack this file and then analyze it.
I've tried some extractors, But It didn't work.

Is there any tools for unpacking and analyzing this file?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try `unzip` first, and come back to ask a more in-depth question...

Comment: After unzip, My main file is "N03_A_E_D_02_11_03.APP", At first I want to unpack it and then analyze unpacked file. I want to know some tools for doing these processes.

Comment: `file` and `binwalk`...

Comment: the ideal way is to have access to application that should create and/or unpack and apply this file. I believe it somehow should be related to Wind River Systems? :)

Comment: Hi and welcome to RE.SE. You might want to have a look at other questions with the [tag:firmware] tag and also include what exactly you've been trying already. Also, your question could be better scoped.

Answer (score 1):

There's ARM Little endian code which starts at offset 0x8466 which seems to be a ZIP archiver code. Then from offset 0x295DF up till the end of the file, there's zlib packed block of data. After unpacking it you get a binary firmware file ~43mb, with ARM little endian code.